# Problem with ordering column in ggplot2 grouped bar chart

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, grouped-bar-chart

I am trying to manually ordinate the columns for this R script ggplot2 Barchart for this locations' order: S. Giorgio, S. Agostino, S.Marinella, Grottini.
I tried using the following script with R but the location S.Agostino disappear and the order is still not correct.

```
ggplot(mydata_2,                                     
       aes(x = location,
           y = values,
           fill = type)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity",
           position = "dodge")

mydata_2$location <- factor(mydata_2$location, levels = c('S. Giorgio', 'S. Agostino', 'S. Marinella', 'Grottini'))
                            
ggplot(mydata_2,                                     
       aes(x = location,
           y = values,
           fill = type)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity",
           position = "dodge")
```

I was trying to order the columns for this ggplot2 bar chart in R without any success. Every time I try the order is not as expected.

Comment: Could you include a small, reproducible example of your data? See this for help: https://www.google.com/url?q=https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example&sa=U&ved=2ahUKEwiKgI2XzIKAAxWNJ0QIHYEoAP0QFnoECAoQAg&usg=AOvVaw1f4a4tqvEFnTuZbpK0j03G

Comment: Redo the data entry and prep from scratch. Now BEFORE you destructively reassign values to `mydata_2$location`, hat does this return? `setdiff(  c('S. Giorgio', 'S. Agostino', 'S. Marinella', 'Grottini'), unique( mydata_2$location) )`. I'm guessing a simple misspelling. Learn not to "destroy the evidence". Instead create new variables and leave the original data unchanged.